# Hibernate to separate partition or file from system swap to prevent failure

Tags: kernel, partition, swap, hibernate

Having done a fair bit of reading and searching for this I don't believe what I am hoping for is possible, but wondered if anyone knows differently.

The issue is my laptop keeps failing to hibernate due to insufficient space. Which it seems means the sum of my swap usage and memory that needs saving (IE can not be discarded and reloaded from disk on resume) exceeds my swap size.

What I would really like to do is separate the hibernate partition / file from the swap partition / file, so that they don't tread on each others space. It seems due to the particulars of resume, having a partition for the hibernate space is the simplest way, and I could either have a separate partition or file for swap. My system swaps fine so I don't really want to play with swapiness, it seems well balanced as it is.

Hibernate will not use a partition without it being active swap from what I have read.

Increasing the size of swap will I assume just mean the machine chomps through yet more swap without preventing hibernation failure 100% as I tend to use a lot of memory, reboots are only every few months (hopefully) and I tend to leave 'stuff' running for months, I assume this is what leads to my overall memory / swap state, but it performs OK for me and speeds up my work flow so prefer not to change it.

Perhaps theres a way to limit the kernels maximum swap use, that will not affect hibernates use. Or a way to tell it to only use one swap device that again will not prevent hibernate using the other device.

EDIT: While its the principle that I'm after rather than specifics its a fairly standard oldish Lenovo with 4GB RAM and a 256GB SSD. Its running Ubuntu 14.04 which does need upgrading yes... Currently its got a 4GB swap partition as I am back trying to get hibernate working reliably, but I'm happy with it running with 2GB, I don't notice any difference. I've tried more in the past (IIRC 6GB) but still had problems hibernating. Never tried more than that though, but at 6GB AFAIK that should be the maximum theoretical amount for 4GB RAM and 2GB swap. I've assumed its using extra swap uselessly when I have the larger swap partition because I notice no difference in performance (basically its this behaviour I want to stop, without limiting the swap partition size, to preserve disk space but facilitate hibernation even when the machine is heavily loaded memory wise). Assume, again, that if given the space it tends to be lazy with regards to reclaiming swap, sensible behaviour probably but clashes with hibernate requirements.

TIA, Pete

Comment: To let other users envision the options you may have: which operating system and version are you using? How much RAM and swap space you currently have? Which kind of drives is your swap space located on, and could further swap space be?

Comment: Read `man swapon mkswap`.

Comment: Thanks Walt but I didn't see anything in those man files that seemed significant. Can make a swap file of a certain size but that size has to be 4GB larger than what I want the kernel to actually be allowed to use for swap itself (to leave enough room for hibernated RAM). Its limiting the kernels swap use that seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Pete Some information about your system was needed because you hadn't mentioned even a kernel family (Linux, a BSD, ...) and it's unlikely that the same principles applied to all of them. Unfortunately, as you said, Linux only hibernates to swap, and there is no guarantee that there will be enough free swap to succeed. Rough ideas for possible workarounds may be: using two swap areas with different priorities (the lower priority given to the bigger area, hoping it will only be used for hibernation); setting up a mechanism that `swapon`s some space as part of the hibernation process.